# What power in outlets forces electrons to flow back to anode in batteries?

Tags: batteries

title pretty much says it all...

I completely understand how battery works (because its simple right?).
But I´m little confused about recharging part... I understand that when you plug battery into the outlet you force electrons to flow back to anode.

But no matter how much I search and watch videos... Nobody describes more closely WHAT IS THIS POWER IN OUTLETS that forces those electrons to flow back?

What is this power that nobody describes? I assume it has to do something with AC/DC current in today outlets?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3KX_KuS6FPI this is one of the examples of the videos where everything is explained briliantly but when it comes to recharging they describe it: POWER in an outlet forces electrons to force back...

But what is that POWER?

thank you so much for your answers and sorry for my noobie question (if it is)
but I really could find anything about this topic

Comment: That power is electricity. The wall socket / charger simply pushes harder than the battery does, so it "goes back in".

Comment: Electromotive force, aka "voltage".

Comment: Look up electroplating.  The specific chemicals are different, but the principle is not unlike what happens in charging a battery.

Comment: The dark power, this is.

Comment: Ahem, when charging, electrons are taken from the anode NOT "you force electrons to flow back to anode".

Comment: Voltage creates an electric field. In the presence of an electric field, any charges which are free to move will do so. They will tend to move along the electric field. Conductors are materials which have free charges (usually electrons).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is absolutely nothing magical about the power in an "outlet". There is simply more of it than there is in a battery.

As a simple illustration, take two rechargeable batteries - one flat and one fully charged. The flat one will have a much lower voltage than the fully charged one. Let's say they're 0.8v and 1.3v respectively.

Connect the batteries to each other in parallel: + to + and - to - (note: don't actually do this, you might overheat and blow up your batteries - just do it in your head).

Now one battery wants the voltage between + and - to be 1.3v but the other can only manage 0.8v. So the stronger battery wins and pulls the voltage up to where it wants it to be. In order to do that it has to "help" the other battery to get there, by giving it some of its charge.

After some time both batteries will find an equilibrium where they have the same amount of charge and both want the voltage to be the same. At that point everything stops. The flat battery has gained a fair chunk of charge, and the charged battery has lost an equivalent amount of charge.

Now the difference with an outlet is purely that there is a seemingly infinite amount of charge to "help" the flat battery reach the voltage that the charger wants it to be - the charger never goes flat - so the flat batter can be "helped" all the way to full charge - and beyond if the charger doesn't know when to stop.

---

<sub>Note to pedants: Yes, this is all completely wrong, but it *paints a picture* that helps the OP understand basic concepts.</sub>

Comment: Like I said. Connect the + of one to the + of the other, and the - of one to the - of the other. There's nothing really to illustrate.

Comment: Now I get it ... So fresh battery takes with his "clean" katode all the electrons from the "dirty" katode of dead battery. And "dirty" anode of dead battery pulls electrons from the "clean" anode of fresh battery. This process of "pulling and pushing" will run until the voltage of dead battery is equal to the voltage of fresh battery... hope I´ve written it comprehensibly...

Answer (score 0):

No magic involved.

The voltage of the charging source must be a little higher than the voltage of the battery being charged - this will cause current to flow from the charging source into the battery.

For a "12 volt" car battery, the charging source can be up to about 14.4 volts while charging, and (with a "smart" charger) will drop to 13.6 volts as the battery reaches full charge..